# Java multithreading - communication between 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I'm trying to learn multithreading in java but i can't seem to find some simple examples on internet that show how 2 threads communicate and pass control between themselves. For example; I want to create simple program which prints txt file, consisting of 2 threads:

1. thread (with higher priority) would ask every 5 lines if i would like to proceed with next 5 lines or terminate program
2. thread would be in control of printing 5 lines that previously 1. thread allowed

My main problem here is, how can i make these threads go in loop, since i can start thread only one time, and i must start program with 1. thread. If someone could put some simple example code with 2 threads communicating or example with this program.

Any help is appreciated, sorry if I forgot some key information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you have described is not a parallel operation. It's sequential: wait for input -> print 5 lines (or quit) -> goto start.

Comment: I know this program can be dealt without threads, but in my assigment we were told to use threads, and i would like to learn how they work, i want to start them at the same time and want them to communicate until all txt file is printed or user decides to stop program

Comment: Well, it's a ridiculous exercise. One must know when to parallelize and when not. But if you want to, you can switch between the threads with a mutual flag and the wait()/notify() mechanism. There's plenty of documentation and tutorials on those.

Comment: agreed but still, if you could put some simple code with wait() /notify() mechanism i would appreciate it :)

Comment: I'm sure you would, but that would be stupid since there are millions of examples already written. You prefer that I write to you, instead of making the effort of going to Google. I don't appreciate that kind of laziness. You're free to ask for clarification here if you don't understand something, but **do not** ask for other people to do your homework.

Comment: very well, its not laziness in question because i googled already alot about threads but none of that helped me with my "program" since i dont know how to put 2 threads in "infinite" loop, but nevermind, thx anyway (btw its not for my homework, that was last week so im not looking for copy past code, just trying to understand threads since they are importan from what i have seen on internet...

Comment: to put a thread in an infinite loop you simply put a while() {} loop in your thread or runnable.

Comment: It is funny how the first thing everyone tried to do with threads is to completely defeat the entire point of threads. The whole point of threads is that threads run separately as independent flows of control, synchronizing only where that is unavoidable.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the downvotings of the question, and with the comments stating the exercise is ridiculous. Of course you would not normally solve the stated problem via threads. But the question poster is learning threads. And the exercise is indeed solvable via threads, and indeed illustrates, even if quite clumsily, communication between threads. When you teach somebody, you often need to bend things to the paths their imagination takes.

Comment: I suspect that the downvotes are more relevant to the inability of the OP to type stuff into a Google seach box than being inexperienced with threads, or even being unable to write a while loop in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Multithreader {

    /**
     * Needs to be volatile because the two thread communicate through it.
     * It is also very important that boolean updates and lookups are atomic,
     * we cannot do the same with for example a long!
     */
    volatile static boolean shouldFilePrinterPrint = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // needs to be final so that the filePrinter can see it
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));

        // this is the task of printing 5 lines from a file whenever shouldFilePrinterPrint is true
        Runnable filePrinter = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    if(shouldFilePrinterPrint){
                        shouldFilePrinterPrint=false;
                        String line;
                        int counter = 0;
                        try {
                            while (counter<5 && (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                counter++;
                                System.out.println(line);
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // this is the task that will set shouldFilePrinterPrint to true every time we push enter
        Runnable inputAwaiter = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        System.in.read();
                        shouldFilePrinterPrint=true;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            }
        };

        // we use the executor service to launch the two tasks in two threads
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executorService.execute(filePrinter);
        executorService.execute(inputAwaiter);

        // I am omitting cleanup such as closing the reader, shutting down the executor service, etc.
        // and am just leaving the program to never terminate until manually stopped,
        // but such cleanup is very important in a real program!
    }
}
```

I think this implements the behavior you described. I ran it, it works.

Note that there is no mention of "Thread" or "synchronised" in this. There is instead "executorService" and "Runnable". There are reasons for that, and they are detailed in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java 2nd edition, a book I very strongly recommend.

Comment: You are welcome! Be careful though: this is indeed a very inappropriate usage of threads, as the other posters mentioned.

Comment: i did not want to put "bad question", or someone to do my "homework", i just wanted to see two threads work together in example like this, so thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You have an inherent misunderstanding of how threading works in Java judging by your statement "show how 2 threads communicate and pass control between themselves".  Threads do not "pass control".  You can have Thread 2 wait(), but even if Thread 1 calls notify(), there is no guarantee which thread will wake up.  In fact, Thread 1 may keep executing for a while.  Rather than trying to predict which thread will be running at any given time, I suggest you create a queue of lines ready to print in Thread 1.  When Thread 2 wakes up, check to see if lines are ready, if not, go back to sleep.

If using wait and notify is one of the parameters of your assignment, this page does a decent job of explaining how to use them appropriately: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html.  Just be aware that calling notify() does not guarantee the thread you want will wake up.  Always use guards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what threads do. By the sounds of it you want sequential processing between two threads, when in fact thread are concurrent, ie they run at the same time.

What you can do is use an Observer pattern where the printing thread observes the input thread. Once the input thread has 5 lines it would pass it to the observer to print. The result would be that the printing thread can be print while the input thread receives more data.